# Check if time in a database surpasses specific hour

Tags: php, html, sql, html-table

I'm making a calendar using PHP  and have run into some issues:

[image: http://imgur.com/mlNxAdT]

I want the calendar to be more automated at the moment as I'm manually creating the table and putting the times and days in myself, which is fine, but my issue is that I'd need a SQL function for every single hour (from 10:00-17:00) for every single day which seems extremely inefficient.

My HTML table code is structured as such:

```
<tr>
  <td>
    <span>
      <p style="float:left">10:00</p>
      <p style="float:right">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;(<?php echo $var->monday_10; ?>)</p>
    </span>
  </td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
```

And I have this PHP function:

```
public function get_CalendarCount($conn)
{
    // TODO: Comment this function
    // TODO: If a booking goes over a time (eg. 13:00) then add to count
    $sql = 
    "
    SELECT DAYNAME(arrivalTime) AS day, COUNT(*) AS count
    FROM bookings
    WHERE HOUR(arrivalTime) = 10
    AND DAYNAME(arrivalTime) = 'Monday'
    ";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) 
    {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
        {
            $this->monday_10 = $row["count"];
        }
    } 
    else 
    {
        echo "0 results";
    }
}
```

As you can see, the time in this example (13.00) and day (Monday) is manually put in. How can I change this so it gets the time / day from the table and keep is as the same function for every td?

Furthermore, I would like to alter my SQL query (as shown in the PHP get_CalendarCount function) so that it checks if a booking in the database  goes over a time (eg. arrivalTime 10:00 - pickupTime 12:00 - both 10:00 and 11:00 need to count as the booking is for the hours 10:00 & 11:00 (1 hour each):

[image: (http://imgur.com/7A0cxGr)]

Would really appreciate help as I'm a bit stuck here, can't really find anything for this solution.

Comment: I think you should grab the data and process it with PHP rather than doing everything via the query.

Comment: JQuery? The function is in PHP.

Comment: He's talking about SQL queries. I disagree with @Stah and think DB logic should be done in the DB.

Comment: I read that as JQuery... my bad. So you think I should store it as a stored procedure in the DB?

Comment: Ah, I get you. Just keep it as a query in PHP. Any ideas how to alter the query to get it to work as I need?

Comment: You need to truncate minutes and for only hours do `pickupTime - arrivalTime` and that would be your count for each hour.

Comment: How do I go around doing that? I've tried and failed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not answering the logic, you should change but the question of using variables in your query, so you don't have to manually put them in. For your question about making the `hour` and `dayname` variable you need to change this:

```
public function get_CalendarCount($conn)
{
$sql ="SELECT DAYNAME(arrivalTime) AS day, COUNT(*) AS count
FROM bookings WHERE HOUR(arrivalTime) = 10 AND DAYNAME(arrivalTime) = 'Monday'";
```

into:

```
public function get_CalendarCount($conn,$hour,$dayname)
{
$sql ="SELECT DAYNAME(arrivalTime) AS day, COUNT(*) AS count
FROM bookings WHERE HOUR(arrivalTime) = ".$hour." AND DAYNAME(arrivalTime) = '" . $dayname ."'";
```

Comment: I'll use Javascript to get the hour and dayname from the table and then pass it. I'll try that once home.