# Count hours between times

Tags: mysql, sql

I asked a similar question a few days ago but didn't quite get an answer for what I'm looking for, specifically with SQL (the question is [Check if time in a database surpasses specific hour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33948503/check-if-time-in-a-database-surpasses-specific-hour)).

Basically, I've got the following query:

```
    SELECT DAYNAME(arrivalTime) AS day, COUNT(*) AS count
    FROM bookings
    WHERE HOUR(arrivalTime) = 13
    AND DAYNAME(arrivalTime) = 'Monday'
```

This will count the number of entries there are for bookings that start at 13:00 on a Monday. How do I change this so that each hour from the arrival time to the pick up time is counted?

For example, if **I had the arrivalTime - pickupTime as 13:00 - 17:00** then 13:00, 14:00, 15:00 and 16:00 would all count this as an entry.

Had a couple of suggestions but didn't really manage to get far with them.

Edit:

The calendar I'm making:
[image]

My database:
[image]

**Samples and expected outputs:**

```
arrivalTime - pickupTime 

13 - 15 (hours 13, 14 are counted)

10 - 14 (hours 10, 11, 12, 13 are counted)

16 - 17 (hours 16 are counted)

13 - 17 (hours 13, 14, 15, 16 are counted)

11 - 12 (hours 11 are counted)
```

Basically, right now it's simply counting the number of entries that have arrivalTime as X. So if we have 10 entries that start at 13:00 on a Monday, on my HTML table that I linked it will have the number 10 next to 13:00. I want to make it that each hour is counting how many bookings actually go over then.

To make it easier to visualise, this is simply put a dog kennel. We're checking to see how many dogs are in the kennel at each hour. Thus, if there's a booking from 13:00 - 15:00 it shouldn't just add a +1 to 13:00 but also to 14:00 as the time overlaps. Maybe a little bit more complex than I thought it'd be.

Edit 2:

Right now I've got this query in my function

```
SELECT DAYNAME(arrivalTime) AS day, COUNT(*) AS count
FROM bookings
WHERE HOUR(arrivalTime) = $hour
AND DAYNAME(arrivalTime) = '$dayname'
```

In HTML I pass the values like so

```
<td>
    <span>
        <p style="float:left">10:00</p>
        <p style="float:right">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;(<?php $var->get_CalendarCount($conn,10,'Monday'); ?>)</p>
    </span>
</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

You mean like this?

```
SELECT DAYNAME(arrivalTime) AS day, COUNT(arrivalTime) AS count
  FROM bookings
  WHERE TIME(arrivalTime) BETWEEN '13:00:00' AND '17:00:00'
  AND DAYNAME(arrivalTime) = 'Monday'
```

Or if you need only 13, 14, 15, 16, 17 then:

```
SELECT DAYNAME(arrivalTime) AS day, COUNT(arrivalTime) AS count
  FROM bookings
  WHERE (TIME(arrivalTime) BETWEEN '13:00:00' AND '17:00:00') 
  AND MINUTE(TIME(arrivalTime)) = 0 
  AND SECOND(TIME(arrivalTime)) = 0
  AND DAYNAME(arrivalTime) = 'Monday'
```

**// EDIT to answer comment**

So you need to count bookings between (example) 13:00 - 17:00 from periods 13:00 - 13.59, 14.:00 - 14:59 etc?

```
SELECT DAYNAME(arrivalTime) AS day, COUNT(arrivalTime) AS count, CONCAT(HOUR(arrivalTime), ':00 - ', HOUR(arrivalTime) + 1, ':00') as Hours
  FROM bookings
  WHERE (HOUR(arrivalTime) BETWEEN '13' AND '17')
  AND DAYNAME(arrivalTime) = 'Monday'
  GROUP BY HOUR(arrivalTime);
```

[image: table]

**// EDIT 2**

Unfortunately I don't have time now to fix the query I wrote, but it would be easier to use a function instead of single select (make select for each one hour period).

But there are two things:

1. If you want it for each hour from ex: 10:00 - 17:00: (ex: 10:00 - 10:59), it would be all records with pickupTime OR arrivalTime between 10:00 AND 10:59
2. if you want then total from this period ex 10:00 - 17:00, it won't be a sum, cuz there will be duplicates, ex: 10:00 - 10:59 may contain same records as 11:00 - 11:59.

**// EDIT 3**

Check if this function will satisfy your needs, when you call it for any cell of your calendar. If you want to return x instead of zero, simply put if and return char. It should work for 10:00 - 10:59 (one hour periods) or 10:00 - 16:59 (total period)

```
CREATE FUNCTION fn_getCount(p_dayName VARCHAR(10), p_fromHour INT, p_toHour INT) 
  RETURNS INT
BEGIN
  DECLARE v_count INT;

  SELECT COUNT(b.arrivalTime) INTO v_count
    FROM bookings b
    WHERE 
      ((HOUR(b.arrivalTime) BETWEEN p_fromHour AND p_toHour - 1) OR
      (HOUR(b.pickupTime) BETWEEN p_fromHour AND p_toHour - 1) OR
      (HOUR(b.arrivalTime) < p_fromHour AND HOUR(b.pickupTime) > p_toHour - 1)) AND
      DAYNAME(b.arrivalTime) = p_dayName;

  RETURN v_count;
END;
```

Call it like this:

```
SELECT fn_getCount('Saturday', 14, 17);
```

I don't know php, I know .NET, but if you want a whole table returned by the server, you can simply make a stored procedure which call this function wherever needed and call the procedure from PHP. I am not an expert but if you want whole calendar returned by the Server, you would have to create pivot table

**// EDIT 4 (30-11-2015 00:04)**

Here you have Function for single cell and stored procedure which generates entire calendar, I have added function to evaluate first day of a week for supplied date, because you need to provide date as well cuz otherwise it will return all Mondays, not only the one from the week you are interested in.

**Function to evaluate single cell:**

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS fn_getCount;
CREATE FUNCTION fn_getCount(p_weekDate DATE, p_dayName VARCHAR(10), p_fromHour INT, p_toHour INT) 
  RETURNS INT
BEGIN
  DECLARE v_count INT;

  SELECT COUNT(b.arrivalTime) INTO v_count
    FROM bookings b
    WHERE 
      ((HOUR(b.arrivalTime) BETWEEN p_fromHour AND p_toHour - 1) OR
      (HOUR(b.pickupTime) BETWEEN p_fromHour AND p_toHour - 1) OR
      (HOUR(b.arrivalTime) < p_fromHour AND HOUR(b.pickupTime) > p_toHour - 1)) AND
      DAYNAME(b.arrivalTime) = p_dayName AND 
      (DATE(b.arrivalTime) BETWEEN fn_firstDayOfWeek(p_weekDate) AND DATE_ADD(fn_firstDayOfWeek(p_weekDate), INTERVAL 6 DAY));

  RETURN v_count;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

**Function to return date of Monday for the week from which we provided a date as parameter.**

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS fn_firstDayOfWeek;
CREATE FUNCTION fn_firstDayOfWeek(day DATE)
  RETURNS DATE
BEGIN
  RETURN SUBDATE(day, WEEKDAY(day));
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

**Procedure to generate entire calendar as pivot table:**

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS sp_GetCalendar;
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_GetCalendar(
  p_weekDate DATE,
  p_fromHour INT, 
  p_toHour INT
)
BEGIN
  DECLARE v_currHour INT;
  DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS Calendar;
  CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE Calendar
  (
    Hours VARCHAR(30),
    Monday VARCHAR(30),
    Tuesday VARCHAR(30),
    Wednesday VARCHAR(30),
    Thursday VARCHAR(30),
    Friday VARCHAR(30),
    Saturday VARCHAR(30),
    Sunday VARCHAR(30)
  );

  SET v_currHour = p_fromHour;
  START TRANSACTION;
  WHILE (v_currHour < p_toHour) DO
    INSERT INTO Calendar (Hours, Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday, Sunday)
      VALUES (
        CONCAT(v_currHour, ':00 - ', v_currHour + 1, ':00'), 
        CASE WHEN fn_getCount(p_weekDate, 'Monday', v_currHour, v_currHour + 1) = 0 THEN 'x' ELSE fn_getCount(p_weekDate, 'Monday', v_currHour, v_currHour + 1) END, 
        CASE WHEN fn_getCount(p_weekDate, 'Tuesday', v_currHour, v_currHour + 1) = 0 THEN 'x' ELSE fn_getCount(p_weekDate, 'Tuesday', v_currHour, v_currHour + 1) END, 
        CASE WHEN fn_getCount(p_weekDate, 'Wednesday', v_currHour, v_currHour + 1) = 0 THEN 'x' ELSE fn_getCount(p_weekDate, 'Wednesday', v_currHour, v_currHour + 1) END, 
        CASE WHEN fn_getCount(p_weekDate, 'Thursday', v_currHour, v_currHour + 1) = 0 THEN 'x' ELSE fn_getCount(p_weekDate, 'Thursday', v_currHour, v_currHour + 1) END, 
        CASE WHEN fn_getCount(p_weekDate, 'Friday', v_currHour, v_currHour + 1) = 0 THEN 'x' ELSE fn_getCount(p_weekDate, 'Friday', v_currHour, v_currHour + 1) END, 
        CASE WHEN fn_getCount(p_weekDate, 'Saturday', v_currHour, v_currHour + 1) = 0 THEN 'x' ELSE fn_getCount(p_weekDate, 'Saturday', v_currHour, v_currHour + 1) END, 
        CASE WHEN fn_getCount(p_weekDate, 'Sunday', v_currHour, v_currHour + 1) = 0 THEN 'x' ELSE fn_getCount(p_weekDate, 'Sunday', v_currHour, v_currHour + 1) END);
    SET v_currHour = v_currHour + 1;
  END WHILE;
  INSERT INTO Calendar (Hours, Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday, Sunday)
    VALUES (
      CONCAT('Total: ', p_fromHour, ':00 - ', p_toHour, ':00'), 
      CASE WHEN fn_getCount(p_weekDate, 'Monday', p_fromHour, p_toHour) = 0 THEN 'x' ELSE fn_getCount(p_weekDate, 'Monday', p_fromHour, p_toHour) END,  
      CASE WHEN fn_getCount(p_weekDate, 'Tuesday', p_fromHour, p_toHour) = 0 THEN 'x' ELSE fn_getCount(p_weekDate, 'Tuesday', p_fromHour, p_toHour) END, 
      CASE WHEN fn_getCount(p_weekDate, 'Wednesday', p_fromHour, p_toHour) = 0 THEN 'x' ELSE fn_getCount(p_weekDate, 'Wednesday', p_fromHour, p_toHour) END, 
      CASE WHEN fn_getCount(p_weekDate, 'Thursday', p_fromHour, p_toHour) = 0 THEN 'x' ELSE fn_getCount(p_weekDate, 'Thursday', p_fromHour, p_toHour) END, 
      CASE WHEN fn_getCount(p_weekDate, 'Friday', p_fromHour, p_toHour) = 0 THEN 'x' ELSE fn_getCount(p_weekDate, 'Friday', p_fromHour, p_toHour) END, 
      CASE WHEN fn_getCount(p_weekDate, 'Saturday', p_fromHour, p_toHour) = 0 THEN 'x' ELSE fn_getCount(p_weekDate, 'Saturday', p_fromHour, p_toHour) END, 
      CASE WHEN fn_getCount(p_weekDate, 'Sunday', p_fromHour, p_toHour) = 0 THEN 'x' ELSE fn_getCount(p_weekDate, 'Sunday', p_fromHour, p_toHour) END);
  COMMIT;

  SELECT * FROM Calendar;
  DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS Calendar;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

**Call them for testing like this:**

```
CALL sp_GetCalendar('2015-11-07', 10, 17);

SELECT fn_getCount('2015-11-07', 'Saturday', 10, 17);

SELECT fn_firstDayOfWeek('2015-11-07');
```

**Output:**

[image]

Code might be a little bit redundant, but I am really short on time.

Comment: Hey, can you check my comment on MM93's answer? Same issue I believe.

Comment: You wanted sth like this?

Comment: Not exactly as it's not specific enough. Check what I edited on my question.

Comment: Hmm, I'm still struggling with being able to do this. Much more complex than I thought. Look at my inputs / expected outputs for a better idea if what I'm looking for (I edited my post). My current query works fine for calculating how many bookings start at a certain time but I need to make it so that each hour checks if another booking goes over said hour.

Comment: Check out the update I made, I hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot for that. Really busy today but will try that ASAP and get back to you.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you need to count even there is no booking in a particular Hour. You need a Hour's table to do this.

```
SELECT H.day_name AS day, 
       Count(b.arrivaltime) AS count 
FROM   hour_table H 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN bookings B 
                    ON h.day_name = Dayname(arrivaltime) 
                       AND h.hours = Hour(arrivaltime) 
WHERE  h.hours BETWEEN 13 AND 17 
       AND h.day_name = 'Monday' 
GROUP  BY H.day_name
```

Edit : If you don't want to count every booking between `X` and `Y`. Then you need conditional Aggregate. Something like this

```
Count(case when h.hours BETWEEN 13 AND 17 then b.arrivaltime .. end) AS count
```

Can add full answer when there is enough information in question

Comment: To visualise it a bit easier here's the calendar I'm making: http://imgur.com/mlNxAdT. Here's my DB: http://imgur.com/7A0cxGr. I don't want to make every booking check the number of counts between X and 17 specifically as this would count a booking that's between 13:00 and 15:00, right? So even 16:00 would add a +1 count, which is of course incorrect.

Comment: @LiamMacmillan - Still am not clear. Can you add sample records and expected output

Comment: Done. Hopefully makes what I'm looking for a little more clear.

Comment: If it's still not clear enough I'll post SQL data with expected outputs in the table.